# App crash just if run on android 7.0 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #108: Error inflating class ImageButton

Tags: android

this is my activity code where app crash
i try in many devices is work fine 
but with any mobile with android version 7.0 crashed

i try chang it to image not work 
when i delete image is work fine 
this is my error  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #108: Binary XML file line #108: Error inflating class ImageButton
if i delete this image in that line 108 give error in another image line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ytubasi.zezo.zezomarket.MyService">




  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">






    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button58"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonblue"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/newsa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Send"
            android:text="@string/myOrders"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,RtlHardcoded" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Candy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/chose_your_order"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Market"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/market"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editTex2t"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/super_market"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton

                    android:id="@+id/phyermace"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/phyermace"
                        android:onClick="phermacy"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Phyrmacy"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/pharmacy"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/IceCream"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/candy"
                        android:onClick="candy"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Restureant"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/candy_and_icecream"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Nuts"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/nuts"
                        android:onClick="nuts"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edwwqitTrext22"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/nuts"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Charge"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/charge"
                        android:onClick="charge"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText2q2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/transfer_and_charge"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Reasturant"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/resterent"
                        android:onClick="resturant"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editTextf2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/restaurant"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Library"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/library"
                        android:onClick="library"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editTrqqext22"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/library"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Perfumes"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/perfum"
                        android:onClick="perfume"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Perfusdsddmes"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/perfumes"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Roses"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rose"
                        android:onClick="roses"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText3vb2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/roses"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/luxury"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/luxyry"
                        android:onClick="luxuary"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editTrext22"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/luxury"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/CofeShopo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/coffe"
                        android:onClick="cofeshop"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText22"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/coffee_shop"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Atarashop"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/atara"
                        android:onClick="attara"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText32"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/atara_shop"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/Bakeries"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/bakeries"
                        android:onClick="bakers"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/bakeries"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/NeedTo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/need"
                        android:onClick="needto"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText21"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="markets"
                        android:text="@string/need_to"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView >
```

Local build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ytubasi.zezo.zezomarket"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
      "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
         'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your local build.gradle file as well? Also, did you install all of the necessary 7.0 SDK packages such as Android SDK Platform, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android Emulator, Android SDK Tools, and Android SDK Platform-Tools?

Comment: i will update it and back again

Comment: Ok, let me know when you do!

Comment: the same problem i update all packages to android 8.0 all packages full

Answer (score 0):

i found android 7.0 and 7.1 crash with  image button  when use xml image as background

i cahnge all image background  to png and work fine